# Can't change payment option on checkout

Tags: commerce

On the checkout process, I have two payment option. When I select the other payment method, the default is still showing. And If I proceed the checkout it goes directly to the completion page without the payment validation. It was working before, what could have changed ?

Thanks

Comment: Any errors in your browser JS console log?

Comment: I think there may be some rules affect direct to completion.

Comment: "It was working before, what could have changed?" - If you are site's manager, you tell us what have changed. Updates? Something installed?